# Difficulty in getting Tensorflow to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

When I enter the following code in the Python interpreter;

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe 
"D:/Programs/Python programs/tensorflow_hw/tf_hw.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in 
swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Programs/Python programs/tensorflow_hw/tf_hw.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed

ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

 File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')

File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
for some common reasons and solutions.  

Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

I've tried Python 3.6.2(both 32-bit and 64-bit) and now i'm running Python 3.5.2(64-bit). I also have the required "dll" file install from the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redistributable software.

My specs:

- Windows 7 Ultimate(64-bit) ; Service Pack 1
- Intel Pentium 2020M processor
- Intel HD Graphics
- Python 3.5.2(64-bit)
- 4GB RAM

I'm unable to solve the problem. Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please reformat your stack trace. It is very hard to read on mobile.

Comment: which version of tensorflow have you installed?

Comment: with Python 3.5, I believe Tensorflow 1.5 should be compatible. With Python3.6 Try Tensorflow 1.7

Comment: @Gnudiff i've reformatted it!

Comment: I've installed tensorflow version 1.8.0 @SuryaTej ok,i'll try using tensorflow 1.5

Comment: Your CPU does not support AVX -- see question & answer above.

Comment: I've got it working with Python 3.6.5(64-bit) and Tensorflow version 1.5.0. It seems that Tensorflow version above that doesn't seems to work. @SuryaTej

Comment: Thanks @P-Gn . I've got it working though.